# How to iterate this mongodb json in pug template

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, pug

i want to iterate this mongodb json as below format

```
index         date

 1        1/18/2019, 11:10:05 PM  
 2        1/18/2019, 11:10:19 PM
 3        1/18/2019, 11:13:29 PM
```

this is my mongodb code

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c420f651967ea6623f96fb2"),
    "username" : "username",
    "type" : "history",
    "date" : [
        "1/18/2019, 11:10:05 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:10:19 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:13:29 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:14:41 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:21:07 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:21:26 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:22:02 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:22:46 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:23:35 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:24:58 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:25:40 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:27:29 PM",
        "1/18/2019, 11:32:30 PM"
    ]
}
```

this is my node js code

```
db.collection("test").find({username: req.session.login, type: 'history'}).toArray(function (err, docs) { 

res.render("history", {history: docs });
```

this is not working pug

```
table.table.table-hover.table-bordered.table-active
            thead
                tr
                    th Number
                    th(scope="col") Login Time
                each a,i in history.reverse()
                    tr
                        td=i+1
                        td=a.date
```

please help me how to do it properly
i have used json stringify method that is not working

Comment: Looks like you have a single record (document) with an array data type containing 10 or so items. So, You just need to store that in a locals variable and iterate over the array. I could give you a better write-up if you displayed all of your code properly. Try cleaning things up a bit for clarity (4-spaces designates code, etc...) Show more of the code in your view as well.

Comment: Please explain how to do it with local variable

Comment: Make sure your getting data from MongoDB

Comment: it is showing data in pug as single row like    1   1/19/2019, 11:56:48 AM,1/19/2019, 11:57:01 AM,1/19/2019

Comment: Then you need to add another loop on pug

Comment: can you show me code how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another loop on the Pug, It should looks like below,

```
table.table.table-hover.table-bordered.table-active
        thead
            tr
                th Number
                th(scope="col") Login Time
            - var sno = 1;
            each a in history.reverse()
                each date in a.date
                    tr
                        td=sno++
                        td=date
```

Comment: i can also do this by    each a , i in history[0].date.reverse()  td=a

Comment: Yes, You can, But you will display first history element

Comment: yes but i want only one user data so i can use findOne method

Comment: Okay, Yes you can use findOne